# Automatic login using PUTTY.EXE with Sudo command

Tags: shell, authentication, putty

I am using below command to open putty through windows command prompt:

```
PUTTY.EXE -ssh -pw "mypass" user@IP -m C:/my.sh -t
```

Where **`my.sh`** mentioned in above command file contains:

```
sudo su - rootuser
```

After executing the command, [putty](/questions/tagged/putty) console is opened and it prompts for password.

Is there any way where I can provide this password automatically without typing it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of a horrible workaround using Expect and embedding a password.
This is a bad idea.

As an alternative:

- Configure sudo to allow `NOPASSWD`.
- Login directly as `root` using public-private key auth.

Both these introduce a degree of vulnerability, so should be used with caution - but any passwordless auth has this flaw.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, I really don't want to configure sudo with NOPASSWD. I am looking for some way where I can configure this in automatic way.

Comment: Look at `expect`. But don't be under any illusions that's somehow more secure, because it isn't.

Comment: 'expect' is something like command in unix. I am sorry, I am not having very good hand on shall scripting.

Comment: You'll hate `expect` then. But yes, it's a scripting language, and about the only way to automate password input in an interactive session. But as it requires embedding the password, it's actually probably less secure than just allowing `sudo` or `root` logins via SSH.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, after struggling for almost whole day, I got the way to get this working.

Below command can be executed from windows machine:

> **PLINK.EXE** -t -ssh -pw "**password**" **user@IP** **/home/mydir/master.sh**

**master.sh** file is located on remote machine. And this file contains below command to execute script with sudo command without prompting password.

> echo  **password** | sudo u **user** -S **script.sh**

Here, **password** should be replaced with your password. **user** should be replaced with your actual user and **script.sh** is the script on remote machine that you want to fire after sudo login.

Comment: This is so unsecure to have root password in a script like that.